# C#: Merge uniform with figure code?

Tags: c#

I have a figure code which detects what pieces of clothing a user is wearing. Here are some examples of some random figure codes.

```
lg-285-76.hr-155-31.sh-300-92.ca-1819-63.hd-209-2.ch-3030-76.
he-3149-1331.sh-3035-110.hr-170-61.fa-3276-72.ch-255-110.hd-209-2.lg-280-1331.
ch-210-110.hd-209-7.hr-828-1407.he-3082-63.lg-280-1408.cp-3309-77.sh-290-92.
```

The two-letter codes indicate the type of clothing, for example:

- `lg` = leg
- `ch` = chest
- `sh` = shoes
- `he` = head
- `hr` = hair

What I want to do is to merge that figure code with a uniform code. Lets say I have a uniform code that I wanted the figure code to be merged with, and that this uniform contained a tshirt and trousers. It would contain the `lg` tag for leg and the `ch` tag for chest.

Uniform string: `lg-285-76.sh-300-92.ch-3030-76.`

What I want to do is to replace the legs, chest etc in the main figure code, and replace them with the one in the uniform string, here is what I have tried so far:

```
public static string ReturnUniform(string uniform, string figure)
{
    string[] uniformParts = uniform.Split('.');
    string[] figureParts = uniform.Split('.');

    foreach (string uniformPart in uniformParts)
    {
        string[] childUniformParts = uniformPart.Split('-');

        if (figure.Contains("." + childUniformParts[0]))
        {
            // remove it from figure parts and replace it with the uniform one here
        }
    }

    return string.Join("", figureParts);
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question.  You have a uniform string for a uniform component say, for the legs.  You want to be able to transform that uniform string to its shoe or chest equivalent?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace what ever body parts are in the uniform string in the figure string, so the figure string is the user wearing the uniform.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *Linq* and *regular expressions* (to parse each line):

```
  string[] figures = new string[] {
    "lg-285-76.hr-155-31.sh-300-92.ca-1819-63.hd-209-2.ch-3030-76.",
    "he-3149-1331.sh-3035-110.hr-170-61.fa-3276-72.ch-255-110.hd-209-2.lg-280-1331.",
    "ch-210-110.hd-209-7.hr-828-1407.he-3082-63.lg-280-1408.cp-3309-77.sh-290-92.",
  };

  // we want "lg", "sh", "ch" in this particular order
  string[] itemsToGet = new string[] { "lg", "sh", "ch" };

  var result = figures
    .Select(figure => Regex
       // Parse each line into name  (e.g. "sh")
       //                      value (e.g. "3035-110")
       //                      index in the itemsToGet (-1 if absent)
       // with a help of regular expression
      .Matches(figure, @"(?<name>[a-z]+)-(?<value>[0-9]+-[0-9]+)\.")
      .OfType<Match>()
      .Select(match => new {
         name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
         value = match.Groups["value"].Value,
         index = Array.IndexOf(itemsToGet, match.Groups["name"].Value) })
       // we want items' names that are presented in itemsToGet only...
      .Where(item => item.index >= 0) 
       // ... and in the right order (as they mentioned in itemsToGet) 
      .OrderBy(item => item.index)
       // item format: "name.value."
       // $"..." (string interpolation) is a C# 6.0 syntax; C# 5.0- alternative  
       // .Select(item => string.Format("{0}.{1}.", item.name, item.value))
      .Select(item => $"{item.name}.{item.value}."))
     // concat all the items back into a string e.g. "lg.285-76.sh.300-92.ch.3030-76."
    .Select(items => string.Concat(items))
     // finally, let's materialize records into an array 
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
   Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome (*extracted* `itemsToGet` names, *order preserved*):

```
lg.285-76.sh.300-92.ch.3030-76.
lg.280-1331.sh.3035-110.ch.255-110.
lg.280-1408.sh.290-92.ch.210-110.
```

Comment: A good solution, but that is one very long `Linq` chain that might need some explaining for less experienced users. (Also could use a disclaimer that this requires C# 6.0.)

Comment: @Pharap: Quite right, thank you! I've edited the answer (comments added, and string interpolation's - C# 6.0 feature - alternative code provided)